# Why Am I getting an error "NoMemory" by Libgit2 when commiting files?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am using Visual Studio Online and Git using Visual Studio 2013 as a client.

I am trying to add files to my repo and when I commit them, I get the following error in the Team Explorer Window:

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. 
Category = NoMemory (Error). Out of memory
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: What kind of file is it? How large is it? Does this always happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking over here => https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/224

This might be due to large binary files. Update the `.gitignore` to ignore very large files. Assuming these are `exe` files add `*.exe` to `.gitignore`

If happens during cloning -  `git tfs clone --ignore-regex=exe http://team-foo $/foo local-foo`

Comment: The poster indicated they're using Git, no mention of the TFS version control system anywhere.

Comment: You're correct. He did point me in the right direction.  I have to find out how to keep these images, yet exclude them from tracking.

Comment: Apologies about the `tfs` the assumption made based on the bug reports filed corresponded with the use of `git tfs` an incorrect assumption in this place. The files can be kept on your local drive and still be ignored through VCS.  If it's dependencies that are the large files - then [tag:NuGet] - http://nuget.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started can be used for dependency management and distribution of large files.

Comment: That indeed looks like trying to load into memory a very large blob, (or a smaller one in a very fragmented memory space from which a large enough continuous memory block cannot be allocated).